# NetSuite: Add new values to multi-select list when importing from csv file

Tags: csv, import, netsuite

I have a .csv file with several records that i need to import. Several of the fields are multi-select which isn't a problem as i use the appropriate connector to separate each entry.

My problem is this: a few of the multi-select fields have values in the csv which don't exist in NetSuite and i was hoping there was a way for these to be added to the list automatically during import or is it that i have to ensure these values are already in the list prior to import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields cannot be added on the fly. The values need to exist prior to import. If you trust the source you could pre-process the csv file to pluck out the multi-select values, condense it into a list and update the list records. Then you'd script the start of the CSV import using a saved csv template.